# How to convert HTML "span" + "input" elements to Number?

Tags: function, math, input, numbers, calculation

Please take a look at the code below:

- I have created random values in JavaScript for the 3 'span' elements
- I am gathering a response from the user via an input set to number type

However, the 'span' and 'input' values are set to NaN.

```js
let text = "";
let num1 = document.getElementById("number1")
num1.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 10) + 10);
let num2 = document.getElementById("number2")
num2.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 5) + 5);
let num3 = document.getElementById("number3")
num3.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
let sum = parseInt(num1.value) + parseInt(num2.value) + parseInt(num3.value);
let yourResponse = document.getElementById("response1");
let yourNumber = parseInt(yourResponse);
let but = document.querySelector("button");
but.addEventListener("click", say)

function say() {
  if (yourNumber.value == sum) {
    text = `${yourNumber}, ${typeof yourNumber}, ${sum}, Great!`;
  } else {
    text = `${yourNumber}, ${typeof yourNumber}, ${sum}, Not quite!`
  }
  let para = document.createElement("p")
  para.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(para);
  console.log(yourResponse, typeof yourResponse);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="number1"></span> + <span id="number2"></span> + <span id="number3"></span> = <input type="number" id="response1">
</div>

<div>
  <button type="submit" id="but">Click to submit</button>
</div>
```

I tried to convert the values with built-in JS functions such as parseInt() or Number(), but this did not fix the issue.

The typeof value is set to number, but the value itself is NaN.

Comment: `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` are HTML elements. You already computed the sum of their values as `sum`, so... probably that in your `if (yourNumber.value == (num1 + num2 + num3))` comparison instead =)

Comment: Thank you Mike! I will need to keep researching because I still can't convert <input type="number" id="response1"></input> object to a number...

Comment: Your num1 through num3 are spans. So you set their value as .textContent (don't use .innerHTML unless you're setting _actual_ HTML code), and you get the value back out with the same .textContent (but why would you: you already know what you're putting in, just save that to an actual number =). Input elements, on the other hand, have a .value property that you use, instead. And in both cases, HTML elements only know strings, so if you're setting values and then getting them back out, remember to turn those strings back into numbers.

Comment: Also you probably want to read the number from the response element not at the point in time when you generate the question, but later after the user clicked the button. So move the line `yourNumber = parseInt(yourResponse.value)` into the `say` function.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you, I could eventually solve my problem thanks to your help. Highly appreciated :)